# How can I test an S3 direct upload with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm using [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) for video uploading direct to S3.  The user visits the page, clicks a div which is a proxy for clicking the form input, selects a file, hits 'ok', and then completes a form while the video uploads.  I'd like to test this with capybara, but it's looking like I'll need to resort to [`#attach_file`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions:attach_file).  Is this my only option?

Comment: Have you sorted this issue ? I'm looking for a something similar.

Comment: I just submitted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the capybara spec, I ended up going with the less-than-desirable approach of:

```
find(:css, '#choose-file').click
```

where my HAML has:

```
.choose-files
  = s3_uploader_form callback_url: videos_url,
    callback_param: 'video[direct_upload_url]',
    id: 's3-uploader',
    expiration: 24.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601,
    max_file_size: 100.megabytes,
    acl: 'public-read' do
    .small.button#choose-file{data: {upload: 'button'}} Choose File
    .hide
      = file_field_tag :file, multiple: true, id: 'upload-input'
    - content_for :javascript do
      :coffee
         $ ->
           $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader
             remove_completed_progress_bar: false
             progress_bar_target: $('#uploads_container')
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to submit an answer to your own question after you resolve it.  You may wind up helping uncountable numbers of people who find your question via Google (like @Leszek)